# grep and find not working in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find

I am trying to grep a particular pattern from a group of files stored in a directory thru shell script. However script scans through the files but it is not fetching me the result. I have 5 files with the pattern as `finishing with status COMPLETE`

Here is the code,could you please help on the issue

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date --d='7 day ago' +'%Y%m%d')
countT=$("find /home/arun/file_status -type f  -name "product_feed_*stock*_${dt}*.out"  -exec grep "finishing with status COMPLETE" {} \;" | wc -l)
echo $countT
if [ $countT -eq 5 ]
then
   echo "Hello"
else
   echo "Hai"
fi
```

The below is the error:

> find /home/arun/file_status -type f -name product_feed_stock_20170504*.out -exec grep finishing: No such file or directory 0 Hai

Comment: The below is the error 
find /home/arun/file_status -type f  -name product_feed_*stock*_20170504*.out  -exec grep finishing: No such file or directory
0
Hai

Answer (score 1):

Need to remove quotes in find command.

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date --d='7 day ago' +'%Y%m%d') 

countT=$(find /home/arun/file_status -type f -name "product_feed_stock_${dt}*.out" -exec grep "finishing with status COMPLETE" {} \;| wc -l) 

echo $countT 
if [ $countT -eq 5 ] 
then 
  echo "Hello" 
else 
  echo "Hai" 
fi
```